# Error when connecting to firebase/firestore: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app in swift and using Firestore to store my data. It’s the first time that I am using Firebase.

Yesterday I connected the `firebase` and `firestore` to my project and everything worked fine. Today suddenly I got an error that It could not connect to the Firestore backend.

> 2020-04-03 13:37:25.851931+0200 Bouwresten[14277:2448929] 6.21.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 time. Most recent error: Network connectivity changed This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Now I know for sure that my computer has a good connection and I am using the simulator of Xcode to test the app. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

This is my appdelegate.swift

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Bouwresten
//
//  Created by Brecht Verhelst on 25/03/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Brecht Verhelst. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

This is the class where I use the firestore to get data, it's called dbhelper

```
//
//  DBHelper.swift
//  Bouwresten
//
//  Created by Brecht Verhelst on 02/04/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Brecht Verhelst. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class DBHelper
{
    var Users = [User]()
    var Products = [Product]()
    init() {
        getUsers()
    }

    func getUsers()  {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("Gebruikers").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let user:User = User(Voornaam: document.get("Naam") as! String, Familienaam: document.get("Familienaam") as! String, Email: document.get("Email") as! String, Wachtwoord: document.get("Wachtwoord") as! String,
                                         Stad: document.get("Stad") as! String, Postcode: document.get("Postcode") as! String, Straat: document.get("Straat") as! String, Nummer: document.get("Nummer") as! String, Added_on: document.get("Added_on") as! String)
                    self.Users.append(user)
                    print(self.Users.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getProducts()  {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("Producten").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let product:Product = Product(Titel: document.get("Titel") as! String, Beschrijving: document.get("Beschrijving") as! String, Prijs: document.get("Prijs") as! Double, Gereserveerd: document.get("Gereserveerd") as! Bool, Added_on: document.get("Added_on") as! String, Gebruiker_id: document.get("gebruiker_ID") as! String)
                    self.Products.append(product)
                }
            }
        }
        print(self.Products.count)
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: How have you installed Firebase / Firestore? If it's through CocoaPods, it might actually be an issue with this. I would try uninstalling and reinstalling the Podfile. Whenever I have a Firebase issue, it's usually because of this, even though Xcode will often claim it's something else. I hope this helps!

Comment: I installed it via the Podfile. I tried to reinstall it but I got the same problem

Comment: Have you found the solution to your issue? Although I don't face the problem off, my client said that they had.

Comment: I had the same issue fixed it by delete and reinstalling 'firebase' from pod file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by deleting my pod file and deleting my firebase connection from my app. Reinstalled it and everything worked perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by syncing my computer and device times.
They were off by a few seconds (roughly 15).

For that, go to settings -> synchronize your clock -> sync now (windows 10).

In my case, firestore only couldn't be reached when the **debugger** was on. You might want to check that. Working on a React Native project here.

Comment: This weirdly solved the issue for me as well. I'm just working on a React project with the Firestore Emulator suite and saw this error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems ok.
I have the same problem with the XCode simulator since a while, but on a real device everything works fine.
So I assume it is an XCode issue/bug which can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug in the most recent version of Firebase (7.14.6), I tried switching to an older version and it worked for me!

1. Change your Firebase version in your package.json to: "firebase":
   "7.14.6
2. Then add the base-64 package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64
3. Add this code snippet to your App.js:

```js
import {decode, encode} from'base-64'; 
if (!global.btoa) {   
  global.btoa = encode; 
} 
if (!global.atob) {   
  global.atob = decode; 
}
```

4. Run npm install in your root folder of your project
5. Try again and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't look anything wrong with your code.

Have you made absolutely sure the device (of Mac/Macbook if you're running on a simulator) has a good internet connection as per the error message?

Side note: You only need to `import Firebase` for all files that use any part of Firebase.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure the device has an internet connection. I'm testing the app on the Xcode simulator. The weird thing is that it only happened since yesterday and before that, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and solved it simply by...

```
allow write
```

In the Rules

Answer (score -1):

Please update your rules with

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read:  if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

See details here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3763

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, that didn't help to solve the problem.